# If I leave game after dying, do I still get a win?

Tags: apex-legends

If I die in the middle of the game and leave the game, will I still get a win for that game if my team were to continue without me and win the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't.

I ragequit a match early while two friends were still alive.  They later turned out to have won the match, however, I didn't see any win stat show up in my profile.  Also to note, the "last match" result didn't show me receiving a win either.

Comment: You are not necessarily the champion in the next game because you won last game